# Cucumber reuse value from previously run scenario

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to reuse a value that was created during the previously run scenario. I am not sure if there is a way in cucumber to make a value available across scenarios.
For instance:

1st scenario:

Given inputOfA

When A is created

Then A is returned

And A contains an Id

2nd Scenario:

Given IdOfA

When customer gets A by Id

Then A is returned.

For the 2nd scenario, it would be great if I can get the Id created from the first without having to persist it anywhere.
Can any of you let me know if this is possible using cucumber or do I have to persist the Id created in the first scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you want.

It would require the scenarios to be executed in a specific order. The scenario execution order isn't specified. It may even be random.

What you want scenarios that are independent. Scenarios you can execute in any order.

If you want to use the result from one scenario in a future scenario, you want to setup the second scenario to execute the same thing as the previous scenario should have done. This may feel like duplication and maybe it is. But the usage of BDD is to drive the implementation. The first scenario was used to drive some behaviour. The second scenario should be used to drive another behaviour.

It is possible that the first scenario can be deleted when the second is implemented. If it is redundant, remove it.

But whatever you do, avoid the path of scenarios that depends on each other. It will only lead to a bad place with seemingly random errors occurring.

Comment: >>you want to setup the second scenario to execute the same thing as the previous scenario should have done

This is what I am doing currently. I was just wondering if what I asked was possible. Thanks for the info.